# Unable to find method 'com.android.build.api.variant.SourceDirectories$Flat com.android.build.api.variant.Sources.getByName(java.lang.String)'

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, sdk

I'm encountering an issue while working on my Android project. I'm receiving the following error message:

```
Unable to find method 'com.android.build.api.variant.SourceDirectories$Flat 'com.android.build.api.variant.Sources.getByName(java.lang.String)''com.android.build.api.variant.SourceDirectories$Flat com.android.build.api.variant.Sources.getByName(java.lang.String)'
```

Im trying use a Firebase for my Android Studio Project. it gave me this error, when i add this code in my build.gradle (module)

```js
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I tought my application is bugged or something, so i tried making new project and try to link the firebase too. but its still error

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that throws that error. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs due to a version mismatch between the Android Gradle Plugin and the Google Services Plugin. To fix it, ensure that both plugins are compatible. The latest version of the Google Services Plugin is 4.3.10, which works with the Android Gradle Plugin version 7.0.4. To update these plugins, simply update your project-level build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

In your app-level build.gradle file, update the Google Services Plugin version at the bottom:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    // your android configuration
}

dependencies {
    // your dependencies
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Google Services plugin

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
}
```

After making these changes, sync your project with Gradle files and the error should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks it work. But why firebase tutorial said the google services version is 4.4.1. But when i tried using 4.4.1 the gradle is error.